# kafka consumer jvm memory usage keep on increasing everyday

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have written a simple kafka consumer using spring-kafka library, consumer does process one message at a time. Following is the configuration for the kafka consumer and container:

```
@Bean
    KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>>
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(2);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        return factory;
    }

    /**
     * default kafka consumer factory
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }


    /**
     * configuration for kafka consumer at thread level.
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {

        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, appConfig.getUgcKafkaBrokers());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        return props;
    }
```

Following is the listener code :

```
 @KafkaListener(id = "testid", topics = "testtopic", clientIdPrefix = "testid")
    public void listen(String data, Acknowledgment ack) {
        String traceId=UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        MDC.put("traceId", traceId);
        logger.info("order reference received is {}", data);
        OrderReference orderRef = gson.fromJson(data, OrderReference.class);
        try {
            // some processing
            ack.acknowledge();
        } catch (SomeException e) {
            logger.error(" error while getting order details {}", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            ack.nack(1);
        } catch (SomeException e) {
            // some processing
            ack.acknowledge();
        }catch (Exception e){
            // some processing
            ack.acknowledge();
        }
    }
```

Following is the memory footprint of the pods which runs these containers . If you see here memory footprint starts increasing every day at 6:30 am because this is the time when this consumer gets data. Next day again same things happens and again memory footprint will increase 3 to 4% . If these keeps going then memory may go to 100% usage.

[image]

Each kafka message is not more than 1 kb and there are 6 partitions and 2 pods running. So that way 3 consumers on each pod are running and they shares 3 partitions per pod.

If consumers polls the messages which is by default 500 messages at a time , I am assuming after commits, these messages should get flushed out of the memory. I am assuming every day when consumers fetches these messages from kafka topic, they are increasing the memory because they are not been garbage collected.

Can someone please explain or suggest a way to fix this.

Comment: Exactly which JVM and which GC are being used?

Comment: Here I am using Open JDK 8 and for GC I have not set anything explicitly for GC.

Comment: It is better to look into a heap dump of this JVM process. Otherwise we don’t know what else you have in this pod.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're adding the traceIds to a HashMap declared as an instance variable:

```
MDC.put("traceId", traceId);
```

I am assuming this "traceId" is some key from message, otherwise why put the traceId in the HashMap?

If you're not managing to clean those it will indeed grow indefinitely.

Comment: here on every new message, I am setting same key traceId in the map,  to a new UUID value and previous one should get garbage collected because of no reference.

Comment: I thought the "tradeId" was just illustrative and that you were giving it an id every time otherwise I  see no reason to doing that. Then I would say there's something in your implementation after the consumer when you do ack.acknowledge() that is causing this. Unless there's a bug in the version you're using. I have many clients with spring-kafka in PRD and I don't have any memory leaks on those applications.

Comment: here I am using traceId along with logback for tracing requests.

Comment: Since you're using spring-kafka and possibly spring boot I would recommend that you add micrometer to check the actual JVM memory usage, you can then monitor: jvm.memory.used.bytes and you will see memory usage of the the actual JVM with all areas included as this you have seems to be a pod memory and the cause can be many others, i.e - you probably using sidecar and have other processes in your pod.